# How i can replace the XNA value with NAN in dataframe using Replace function?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have a dataframe which contains 36 columns and 1 600 000 rows. I have XNA value in data so when i try to find null value using `df.isnull().sum()`. the xna value didnot count so for count that i have to replace xna value with Nan so, how i can do that?

Comment: Please specify what you have tried and what did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2], ["test", "NXA", "test2"]]).T
df.columns = ["col1", "col2"]

df.col2.replace("NXA", np.nan)
```

to replace all "XNA" value in col2 with missing values in numpy / pandas format.